# How to decrease space above and below displayed equations

Tags: equations

This is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,enumitem}

\begin{document}
How can I decrease vertical space between text above and below \$\$ \ldots \$\$ ?
$$x^{2}+y^{2} = 1$$
How can I decrease vertical space between text above and below \$\$ \ldots \$\$ ?

And how can I decrease vertical space between text above and below align command ?
\begin{align*}
abdefg &= 1\\
     &\leq 2.
\end{align*}
How can I decrease vertical space between text above and below align command ?
\end{document}
```

And it shows as this picture
[image]

Everyone know how to fix it? Please help.

Comment: It is the default space. Maybe it is too big because you don't have material enough on the page to fill. Insert a lot of text (using `\lipsum[1]` from the `lipsum` package, for example) and see if the vertical space is smaller.

Comment: Also, don't use double dollar. Use `\[ \]` instead.

Comment: @sigur It does not different.

Comment: So, don't worry. Just let TeX decide to you. When you finish your document you can try some adjustment.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The spacing above equations is determined by the length `\abovedisplayskip` while the spacing below them is determined by the length `\belowdisplayskip`, so, modify them to achieve what you want, for example,

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{3pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{3pt}

How can I decrease vertical space between text above and below \$\$ \ldots \$\$?
\[x^{2}+y^{2} = 1\]
How can I decrease vertical space between text above and below \$\$ \ldots \$\$?

And how can I decrease vertical space between text above and below align command?
\begin{align*}
abdefg &= 1\\
     &\leq 2.
\end{align*}
How can I decrease vertical space between text above and below align command?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You may also want to mention the parameters `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip`, which come into play if the last line immediately before an equation is, well, short.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the comment. But that's already in the duplicate link...

Comment: with answers like this one, I always wonder how the author even found out that X determines the length before/after Y, in this case X=`\abovedisplayskip`, Y=equation

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Also `\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}` affect to equation spacing behaviour.

Comment: Has no effect, but I'm using the LNCS style template from Springer.