# Beamer: extra blank line between display math and enumerate

Tags: beamer, line-breaking, enumerate, displaybreak

I use the beamer class. If display math followed by some enumerate environment, beamer will insert an extra blank line between them.

The following is the codes.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
      Assume
      \[
        f+g=h
      \]
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item item 1;
        \item item 2.
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
      Assume
      \[
        f+g=h
      \]
      then
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item item 1;
        \item item 2.
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The `pdf` file looks like the picture.
[image]

I split the frame into two columns.
In the left column, there is no texts between display math and the enumerate environment. But there is an extra blank line, as if there are some ghost texts between them.

**Question:** How to remove the extra blank line?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/615437/263192

Comment: If you are interested in a quick fix: adding a blank line between the end of the equation and `\begin{enumerate}` reduces the space. Alternatively, you could use a negative `\vspace`.

Answer (score 2):

Placing a negative `\vspace` works.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
      Assume
      \[
        f+g=h
      \]
      \vspace{-1.5em} %Placing a negative \vspace works. Adjust it according to your need.
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item item 1;
        \item item 2.
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\linewidth}
      Assume
      \[
        f+g=h
      \]
      then
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item item 1;
        \item item 2.
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think the solution in this case will be the Tikz library usage to draw your algorithm or just making the table where you can put your info:

```
begin{table}{c|c|c}
Assume & & Assume \\
\[f+g=h\] & & \[f+g=h\] \\
 & then & \\
1. item 1; & & 1. item 1;\\
2. item 1; & & 2. item 1;\\

end{table}
```

Comment: Did you actually test this code? There are at least 3 errors.

Comment: try tabular instead of table and use appropriate library \usepackage{tabularx}

Comment: It is your task to use the correct environment name, not something your readers have to try. And the incorrectly used `table` is not the only error

Comment: I don't know what compiler do you have but overleaf's compiler noticed only this one. Will it be ok if I delete this answer with all comments, because I've posted another one?

Comment: Overleaf is good at hiding error messages. It is your job as a user to check the log file to see if there are any problems.

Comment: You can delete it, but be careful with deleting too many downvoted answers, this can result in an automatic answer ban by the website. Usually you should edit your posts to fix problems instead of deleting them.

Comment: ;) yeah, got it. I didn't know that Overleaf is hiding errors...Going to use MikTex instead of it

Comment: Better use texlive. That's usually more up-to-date than miktex and has less packaging errors.

Comment: Thanks for useful comments. I appreciate your contribution

Answer (score -1):

This code will give you a table withour additional spaces:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c c c}
Assume & & Assume \\
\(f+g=h\) & & \(f+g=h\) \\

 & then & \\
1. item 1; & & 1. item 1;\\
2. item 1; & & 2. item 1;\\

\end{tabular}


\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Neither or the loaded packages is necessary and you really should not place any test outside of frames in beamer. What's the purpose of the section?

Comment: Do you mean that amsmath package is not required? How do you suggest to write formulas?

Comment: Your formula does not use any special macros which would require amsmath. However beamer automatically loads it anyway, so even if you were to use something from amsmath, you wouldn't have to load it.

Comment: Yeah, now I see that beamer class has already have it and code works without additional tabularx and amsmath libraries

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the desired result is the picture given in Rahman's answer. A negative `\vspace` is acceptable if there is no better solution.

Comment: @jiaopjie, OK, do you mean that it is enough to place the \vspace negative solution? I suppose that shorter programm is better program and here we need more complex soluton. But if you're satisfied with Rahman's solution it is OK

Comment: @Programmer1988 I mean the desired result is just like Rahman's picture. I want some better solutions, than a negative `\vspace`.  But if there is no one, the latter is acceptable. In my example, the right column is just for comparison. My needs is not to recurrent my picture using other methods.